# C# MySQLDataReader replace in result

Tags: c#, mysql, select, replace

I need replace in my MySQL result "," for "."

```
string.Replace(",", ".");
```

current code:

```
mysql.Connection.Open();

        mysql.Command.CommandText = query;
        mysql.Reader = mysql.Command.ExecuteReader();

        string new_ = String.Empty;

        while (mysql.Reader.Read())
        {
            /*
            foreach(var field in mysql.Reader)
            {
               // what i do here?
            }
            */

            // here i have code to add to TextBox value
        }
```

I have no idea how to replace... i tried some like
field = string with replace
but Visual Studio cant take this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably wanna store all those replaced strings somewhere,

so you can make a list:

```
List<string> replacedStrings = new List<string>();
string replace = "";

     while (mysql.Reader.Read())
    {

        foreach(var field in mysql.Reader)
        {
          replace = field.replace(',','.');
          replacedStrings.add(replace); //<-- add each replaced string to the list
        }
     }
```

Comment: Yes this i thinked to do it... with List.. but i dont know how to code it right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
result = mystring.Replace(',', '.');
```

where mystring is whatever string you are trying to edit

Answer (score 1):

You could do the replace right in the select statement, like this:

```
    Select REPLACE('first.second.third', '.', ',')
```

The select above would yield 'first,second,third'. Another example would be:

```
    Select REPLACE(MyColumnWithCommasInIt, '.', ',') From MyTable
```

The select above would yield the values from MyTable.MyColumnWithCommasInIt with the periods replaced with commas.

More info in the MySQL reference for [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: Here i could kill self... about 85 columns :D